# SoapClient class not found

Tags: laravel, docker, soap, soap-client, laradock

I use Laradock for managing my docker containers. I see `class SoapClient not found` every time I call `SoapClient`. Simple soap installation do nothing even after php-fpm restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to enable all soap variables in laradock `.env` and rebuild both `php-fm` and `workspace` containers. You can do that with this commands

```
docker-compose build php-fpm
docker-compose build workspace
```

If you see any error while trying to install soap in both containers try to change both dockerfiles: find line where install soap command is called may look like this

`apt-get -y install libxml2-dev php-soap && \`

and add this line before it

`apt-get update && \`.